# getting jquery ajaxStop to only fire once everytime

Tags: ajax, jquery

For some reason my ajaxStop code is firing twice right now and I need to limit it to just one time.

```
$('.submit').bind('click', function(e) {

$("#fileupload").ajaxForm({
        target: '#status'
}).submit();


$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
         var mysrc = $("#status").find('img').attr("src");
         $(".empty:first").removeClass("empty").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-state").append('<img src="'+mysrc+'" width="45" height="60" class="expand"/>');
     });     

});
```

Comment: ajaxStop has stopped the ajax requests, but when I run the click again now I'm getting two items again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try using [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), like:

```
$(document).one("ajaxStop", function() {
   var mysrc = $("#status").find('img').attr("src");
   $(".empty:first").removeClass("empty").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-state").append('<img src="'+mysrc+'" width="45" height="60" class="expand"/>');
});
```

Comment: This does indeed limit it to firing once, however it fires before all the ajax calls finish.  For me, anyway...

Comment: This is getting called even before calls are being made, so this is a wrong answer.

Comment: This worked for me. Saved me from doing `$(this).unbind("ajaxStop")`.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was executing twice as well.  However, using .one meant that it only fired on the FIRST iteration, which wasn't after everything completed.  Here is what I ended up using, and it seems to work as desired.

```
var ajaxCount = 0;

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    ajaxCount += 1;
    if (ajaxCount == 2) {
        $('.fieldLoading').hide();
        $('.fieldValue').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: What if it's three or four calls but I only want to fire on the last request? +1 for the solution.

Comment: It's been so long I don't remember any context, but obviously if you KNOW how many requests it's making, just change the line `if (ajaxCount == 2) {`, replace the `2` with however many it makes.